# Spring Boot OAuth2.0 authorization problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

How can user get data through Spring Boot OAuth 2.0? The user can do authentication, but cannot then receive the data.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/addPet").access("hasAnyAuthority('USER', 'ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").access("permitAll")
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("login").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .and().oauth2Login().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().csrf().disable();
}

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select login, password, enabled from users where login=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select login, role from users where login=?");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can get information from the site in this way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/addPet").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").access("permitAll")
            .and().oauth2Login().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")


            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("login").passwordParameter("password")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").and().csrf().disable()

    ;

}
```